# Layer not shown when plotting multiple layers using tmap

Tags: r, tmap

I am trying to plot three layers using the `tmap` package in R, but one of the layers is not shown in the map. I am not allowed to share the data and the map, but this is how my code looks like:

```
library(tmap)

tm_shape(data1) +
   tm_fill(col = "variable1") +
tm_shape(data2, is.master = TRUE) +
   tm_borders() +
tm_shape(data3) +
   tm_lines(col = "variable3", palette = "Greys")
```

The first two layers containing polygons are plotted correctly (the first one with the colour inside the polygons and the second one with borders. But the third layer, containing lines is not shown in the map. It is shown in the legend, but not in the map. Does anyone have any idea where the problem might be coming from?

Answer (score 0):

It is really difficult to help you if you are not allowed to share the data.  I suspect that it may be related with the data, and not with `tmap`, but I can't confirm.

Some tips that may help:

1. Try to plot your lines alone: e.g. `tm_shape(data3) +  tm_lines(col = "variable3", palette = "Greys")` to see if it is a layer-related problem or not.
2. Change the palette and increase the width to double-check: `tm_shape(data3) + tm_lines(col = "variable3", palette = "Set1", lwd = 3)`

For info, I tried to re-create your issue but everything seems fine:

```r
library(giscoR)
library(tmap)


# Mock your data
# Polygons
data1 <- gisco_get_nuts(nuts_level = 0)
data2 <- gisco_get_nuts(nuts_level = 1, country = "Germany")
data3 <- gisco_get_nuts(nuts_level = 2, country = "Germany", spatialtype = "BN")

# Add dummy vars
set.seed(1234)

data1$variable1 <- sample(1:2, nrow(data1), replace = TRUE)
data3$variable3 <- sample(1:4, nrow(data3), replace = TRUE)


# Plot

tm_shape(data1) +
  tm_fill(col = "variable1") +
  tm_shape(data2, is.master = TRUE) +
  tm_borders()  +
  tm_shape(data3) +
  tm_lines(col="variable3", palette = "Greys") +
  tm_layout(legend.outside = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your reply and the effort to recreate the problem! I plotted the lines alone and that works well - they are mapped. Only when plotted together with the other two layers they are not shown. I also increased the width of the lines, and they are still not visible in the map. In the legend I can see that the width increases, but still nothing in the map.

Comment: It seems that the third layer is in latitude and longitude, while the other two are in EPSG28992. There is an argument projection and the list of supported projections in tmap, but EPSG28992 is not there. I tried to change the projection using sf, but that changes the object class. Is there a way to keep the SpatialLinesDataFrame and to change its projection, so I can plot it in tmap with the other layers?

Comment: You can swap from sf to sp with `as(x, "Spatial)`. My advice is to work on `sf` as much as you can (it supersedes `sp`) and in need switch the objects to `Spatial*` as I mentioned.

Comment: The reverse transformation (sp to sf) can be done with `st_as_sf()`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I switched to sf, changed the projection, and then switched back to sp, but then it seems back to latitude and longitude. I tried to plot both sf and sp objects using my code above, but in both cases the layer is not drawn. :(

Comment: Did you try `st_transform(data3, 28992)`?  After that coords shouldn’t be on lon/lat. As I said, really hard to give you more info on this whithout the data

Comment: Thanks! I have now tried this and it gives the following error: Error in UseMethod(st_transform): no applicable method for 'st_transform' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialLinesDataFrame', 'SpatialLines', 'Spatial', 'SpatialVector', 'SpatialLinesNULL')"